# how to solve android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,

Tags: java, android

My app is crashing sometimes and sometimes it work fine.I am generating random numbers and then using them to retrieve data from database with those numbers as id.Sometimes the app runs successfully but some time it crashes with the above mentioned error.

**gamedatabase.java**

```
public String getquestion(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { key_rowid, key_ques, key_one,
            key_two, key_three, key_four, key_answer };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table, columns, key_rowid + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String qstn = c.getString(1);
        return qstn;

    }

    return null;
}

public String getopt1(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { key_rowid, key_ques, key_one,
            key_two, key_three, key_four, key_answer };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table, columns, key_rowid + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String qstn = c.getString(2);
        return qstn;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getopt2(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { key_rowid, key_ques, key_one,
            key_two, key_three, key_four, key_answer };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table, columns, key_rowid + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String opt1 = c.getString(3);
        return opt1;
    }
    return null;

}

public String getopt3(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { key_rowid, key_ques, key_one,
            key_two, key_three, key_four, key_answer };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table, columns, key_rowid + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String opt3 = c.getString(4);
        return opt3;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getopt4(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { key_rowid, key_ques, key_one,
            key_two, key_three, key_four, key_answer };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table, columns, key_rowid + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String opt4 = c.getString(5);
        return opt4;
    }
    return null;
}

public String ans(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { key_rowid, key_ques, key_one,
            key_two, key_three, key_four, key_answer };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table, columns, key_rowid + "="
            + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String answ = c.getString(6);
        return answ;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] coloumns = new String[] { key_rowid2, key_score };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table2, coloumns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    int irow = c.getColumnIndex(key_rowid2);
    int iscore = c.getColumnIndex(key_score);
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(irow) + " " + c.getString(iscore)
                + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public String getscore(int l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] coloumns = new String[] { key_rowid2, key_score };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(database_table2, coloumns, key_rowid2
            + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        result = c.getString(1);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**game.java**

```
public class game extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv4;
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    String correctans;
    Random ran=new Random();
    int k;
    int rand;
    int score = 0;
    int l, i = 0;
    int[] no=new int[10];
    //int no[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int b[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //int no[] = { 20, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        int rand=ran.nextInt(30);
        int t = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<10;k++)
        {
            if(k==0)
                no[0]=rand;
            else
            {
                while(t!=k)
                {
                    t=1;
                    for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
                    {
                        if(no[j]==rand)
                        {
                            rand=ran.nextInt(30);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            t++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                no[k]=rand;
            }
        }
        final Context context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        l = no[i];
        getdata(l);
    }

    private void getdata(int l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (i < 10) {
            gamedatabase info = new gamedatabase(this);
            info.open();
            String question = info.getquestion(l);
            String opt1 = info.getopt1(l);
            String opt2 = info.getopt2(l);
            String opt3 = info.getopt3(l);
            String opt4 = info.getopt4(l);
            correctans = info.ans(l);
            info.close();
            tv1.setText("Question  " + (i + 1) + "/10");
            tv2.setText(question);
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv4.setText("YOUR SCORE IS " + score);
            tv4.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            b1.setText(opt1);
            b2.setText(opt2);
            // b2.setTextColor(color.darker_gray);
            b3.setText(opt3);
            // b3.setTextColor(color.darker_gray);
            b4.setText(opt4);
            // b4.setTextColor(color.darker_gray);
            i++;
        } else if (i > 9) {
            final Context context = this;
            Bundle basket = new Bundle();
            basket.putInt("score", score);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, score.class);
            i.putExtras(basket);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            if (b[i] != 1) {
                if (correctans.equals("a")) {
                    score = score + 10;
                    correctdial();
                    b[i] = 1;

                } else if (correctans != "a") {
                    score = score - 5;
                    incorrectdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                dialog();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if (b[i] != 1) {
                if (correctans.equals("b")) {
                    score = score + 10;
                    correctdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                } else if (correctans != "b") {
                    score = score - 5;
                    incorrectdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                dialog();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            if (b[i] != 1) {
                if (correctans.equals("c")) {
                    score = score + 10;
                    correctdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                } else if (correctans != "c") {
                    score = score - 5;
                    incorrectdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                dialog();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            if (b[i] != 1) {
                if (correctans.equals("d")) {
                    score = score + 10;
                    correctdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                } else if (correctans != "d") {
                    score = score - 5;
                    incorrectdial();
                    b[i] = 1;
                }
            } else {
                dialog();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void dialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog alert3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(game.this).create();
        alert3.setTitle("YOU HAVE ALREADY ANSWERED THAT QUESTION");
        alert3.setMessage("PRESS CONTINUE TO MOE FORWARD");
        alert3.setButton("CONTINUE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (i < 10) {
                    getdata(no[i]);
                } else {
                    getdata(10);
                }

            }
        });
        alert3.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void incorrectdial() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(game.this).create();
        alert2.setTitle("OOPS!!!!!!IT'S INCORRECT\nBETTER LUCK NEXT TIME");
        alert2.setMessage("Your score is" + score);
        alert2.setButton("CONTINUE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (i < 10) {
                    getdata(no[i]);
                } else {
                    getdata(10);
                }
            }
        });
        alert2.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void correctdial() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(game.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("YEAH!!!!!!!!THAT IS THE CORRECT ANSWER\nGREAT GOING");
        alert.setMessage("Your score is" + score);
        alert.setButton("CONTINUE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (i < 10) {
                    getdata(no[i]);
                } else {
                    getdata(10);
                }
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

**Log Cat**

```
08-12 08:52:52.995: I/Choreographer(1250): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-12 08:52:54.215: D/AndroidRuntime(1250): Shutting down VM
08-12 08:52:54.215: W/dalvikvm(1250): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.example.fifaworldcupquiz.gamedatabase.getquestion(gamedatabase.java:174)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.example.fifaworldcupquiz.game.getdata(game.java:85)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.example.fifaworldcupquiz.game.access$0(game.java:79)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.example.fifaworldcupquiz.game$3.onClick(game.java:238)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-12 08:52:54.275: E/AndroidRuntime(1250):     at   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope some one could help

Comment: Your question is very wordy and you've posted a lot of code. Could you try to remove code that is unrelated to your issues? What part of you code throws the exception?

Comment: @JohnSterling +1 I second that. You should point out where it is giving you the Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your cursors don't contain any result rows.

Replace all cases like

```
if (c != null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
```

with

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
```

`SQLiteDatabase` queries never return a `null` and you need to ensure the `Cursor` points to a valid row before accessing its data. `moveTo..()` returns true in such cases.